# Identity server 4 - GetToken slowness intermittently

Tags: performance, identityserver4, access-token

We have implemented Identity server 4 for our API suite and we have a SLA of 6 secs for the clients that consume our service.

What we have observed is first request of the day to generate the token for all the clients takes around 6-7 seconds, subsequent request takes 100-200ms.

We are unable to pinpoint the setting that is contributing to this, as we do not reset AppPool/IIS.

Any help here would be appreciated.

PS: We fetch clients from DB and all the token settings are being set here.

Comment: if the app is recycled (via IIS), then app takes a long time to boot up the dbcontext from scratch. You might benefit from using EF Core 6's compiled models https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-6-0-preview-5-compiled-models/

Comment: Let me try your suggestion by adding more logs.
 The app is not recycled your suggestion makes sense if the app is reinitilaized, is there a default recycle time on IIS?

Comment: I would just add a service that pings the instance on regular interval as a way to make sure it is always running.

Comment: Is it 6-7 seconds for each unique client or just one 6-7 second request?

Comment: Its 6-7 seconds for each unique client

Comment: Ok here is an update on the issue for the token generation code that is being used as below:
'var discoveryEndpoint = await Helper.CreateDiscoveryDocument(client, configuration);
 var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest()
            {
                Address = configuration.GetSection(IdentityServer).Value,
                Policy = { RequireHttps = false }
            });
           
as we are using calling of CreateDiscoveryDocument is not necessary as the identity server URL can be passed directly. Changing it saved couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is an update on the issue for the token generation code that is being used as below:

```
 var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new 
 DiscoveryDocumentRequest()
        {
            Address = configuration.GetSection(IdentityServer).Value,
            Policy = { RequireHttps = false }
        });
```

as we are using JWT calling of CreateDiscoveryDocument is not necessary and the identity server URL can be passed directly. Changing this saved couple of seconds.

However, I am still wondering why this happens for every client any thoughts?